# Remove element from an array of objects and create array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

Rewriting the question with detailed example:

I have array of objects with three property, I would like to build array of harsh and have the resulting hash not have @name instance property. I have simulated the problem with an example.

#### example creation

```
class Employee
  attr_accessor :name, :company, :duration
  def initialize(name, company, duration)
    @name     = name
    @company   = company
    @duration = duration
  end
end

aSong1 = Employee.new("Fleck", "AMZ", 260)
aSong2 = Employee.new("Taylor", "EMC", 120)
aSong3 = Employee.new("Bob", "Adobe", 260)
aSong4 = Employee.new("Jack", "Google", 360)

final_array = [ ]
final_array.push(aSong1)
final_array.push(aSong2)
final_array.push(aSong3)
final_array.push(aSong4)
```

#### controller

```
puts final_array.length #4
final_array.each do | element | 
  puts element.is_a?(Object) #true
  puts element.name #prints name
end
```

#### resulting array ( expected )

```
result = [{company: 'AMZ',duration: 260}, {company: 'EMC',duration: 120},{company: 'Adobe',duration: 260}, {company: 'Google',duration: 360}  ]
```

Example: [repl](https://repl.it/NrGK/1)

Comment: Are you sure that this is not something that should be done in the DB instead of pulling a bunch of data out and sorting it in Ruby?

Comment: I'm trying to handle this in controller as of now, as it has lot of dependencies to change in the DB side.

Comment: Its also very unclear what you mean by " In next step i would like to compare this array of objects against array of hash's (example:compare)to see if i find any matching to update name". What is the input and what should the output be?

Comment: Removing the id can be done with `@user_data.map {|h| h.except("id") }`

Comment: @ I meant once the id is removed I would like to compare the result with `example: compare` code snippet to find if I have any match

Comment: Can you please just provide input and expected output as requested?

Comment: @max when I tried delete or except it says method undefined. perhaps the result would be `[{company: "ABZ",name: "Bob"}]`

Comment: Edit the question and provide the requested clarifications....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158361/discussion-between-mad-d-and-max).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final_array.collect {|x| { company: x.company, duration: x.duration }}
```

result:

```
[{:company=>"AMZ", :duration=>260}, {:company=>"EMC", :duration=>120}, {:company=>"Adobe", :duration=>260}, {:company=>"Google", :duration=>360}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the id keys using

```
 a = [{"id":"21","company":"AMC","name":"Matt"},{"id":"22","company":"AMC","name":"Jon"},
{"id":"12","company":"XYZ","name":"Bob"}].each{|o| o.delete :id}
```

If you want to compare it with other hashes you can use the merge method assuming a2 is the second Hash

```
a.merge(a2)
```

This will return a new hash with any matching keys updated with new corresponding values from the second hash

Comment: `o.delete "id"`

Comment: I tired it for some reason it didn't work :/ supplying the argument as symbol did the job though

Comment: @yassine2020 `undefined method `delete' for #<EmpServices::DataEntry:0x007fe9ba061638>`

Comment: Make sure you are getting Hashes inside the Array

Comment: `entry.is_a?(Object)  # => true`

Comment: What about the Hashes inside?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
class Employee
  def to_h
    instance_variables.each_with_object({}) do |var, h|
      k = var.to_s.tr('@','').to_sym
      v = instance_variable_get(var)
      h[k] = v
    end
  end
end

result = final_array.map{|e| e.to_h.delete_if{|k,v| k == :name}}
```